# How to override the text color in TextField in Jetpack Compose using MaterialTheme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to use `TextField()` from Jetpack Compose. I want the text color to be white.

I found this to be working:

```
ProvideTextStyle(TextStyle(color = Color.White)) {
   TextField(
       ...
   )
}
```

However, I want to override this in the Theme level, so that I don't need to repeatedly write `ProvideTextStyle`. I saw that `MaterialTheme` only accepts the following params:

```
@Composable
fun MaterialTheme(
    colors: Colors = MaterialTheme.colors,
    typography: Typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
    shapes: Shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

So I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone help?

*(compose version = 1.0.0-alpha11)*

Comment: You can define colors like this (colors is parameter od TextField): colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(textColor = YourColor)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I want to override this in the Theme level

Modify the content of `MaterialTheme` composable in your app's theme composable to include TextStyle.

```
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = TextStyle(color = Color.White),
                content = content
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Now your provided `TextStyle` will be used at App theme level.

```
setContent {
    MyAppTheme {
        // app content
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. We are setting the color scheme to the whole `MyAppTheme`.

Answer (score 25):

As [Adrian Grygutis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6049708/adrian-grygutis) pointed out on the comment, in `1.0.0`, `TextField` has a parameter `colors`. You could customize your `TextField` by calling `TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(...)` with the parameter you want to change.

```
TextField(
    ...
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(textColor = Color.White),
) {
```

As for theming, and if you want to avoid calling every time:

```
ProvideTextStyle(TextStyle(color = Color.White)) {
   TextField(
       ...
   )
}
```

You could create a composable with your own set of `TextFieldColors` and add it as a parameter in your `TextField`. You could for instance, have all colors as white:

```
@Composable
fun MyAppTextFieldColors(
    textColor: Color = Color.White,
    disabledTextColor: Color = Color.White,
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.White,
    cursorColor: Color = Color.White,
    errorCursorColor: Color = Color.White,
    ...
) = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
    textColor = textColor,
    disabledTextColor = disabledTextColor,
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    cursorColor = cursorColor,
    errorCursorColor = errorCursorColor,
    ...
)
```

To avoid calling this in every `TextField`, you can then create a custom `MyAppTextField` for your app that calls the default `TextField` with your custom `TextFieldColors` as a default parameter:

```
@Composable
fun MyAppTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    ...
    colors: TextFieldColors = MyAppTextFieldColors(),
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = modifier,
        ...
        colors = colors,
    )
}
```

That way, you would only need to call `MyAppTextField`. It's a good way to override colours inherited from the theme if needed.

Answer (score 14):

The M2 `TextField` `contentColor` is based on `LocalContentColor.current`. You can use the [**`CompositionLocalProvider`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal) to provide a custom `LocalContentColor`.

You can define a custom function like:

```
@Composable
fun ContentColorComponent(
    contentColor: Color = LocalContentColor.current,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides contentColor,
        content = content)
}
```

It can be used with many components, for example the `TextField`:

```
ContentColorComponent(contentColor = Color.Blue) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to apply this to a BasicTextField and it doesn't work, any hint? To make it work I have to change the style like this:  `textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = fontSize.sp, color = fontColor)`

Answer (score 5):

In `1.0.0-beta07` you are able to use the `textStyle` property to override the style and therefore the content color. Also, see [Styling TextField](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#styling-textfield).

```
TextField(
   ...
   textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Blue) 
)
```

Comment: This only changes the color of the value being typed into the textfield, how do you change the label color aswell?

Comment: TextField(
        value = name,
        onValueChange = {},
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White),
        label = {
            Text(text = label,
                 modifier = Modifier,
                 color = Color.White,
                 style = TextStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic))
        },
        readOnly = true
    )

Comment: (i.e. you can directly set the 'color' argument in the Text element contained within the "label" parameter)

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own `TextField` Widget with desired `color` and use it across all places,

```
@Composable
fun ColoredTextField(value: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit){
    ProvideTextStyle(TextStyle(color = Color.White)) {
        TextField(value = value, onValueChange = onValueChange)
    }
}
```

Now start using `ColoredTextField` instead of `TextField` and by changing `color` in your `Widget`, it gets applied to all the places.

Comment: Thanks! This can be a nice solution, but I was hoping there is a way to do it on the theme level.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your application's `MaterialTheme` with your own `Color` object configuration, setting the content color parameters (`onPrimary`, `onSecondary` and so on).

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = Colors(
        primary = Color.Black,
        secondary = Color.Black,
        background = Color.Black,
        onPrimary = Color.Red,
        onSecondary = Color.Red,
        onBackground = Color.Red
    )
)
```

Note: for the font colors to take effect, you must set the main colors (`primary`, `secondary` and so on). This is due to the logic defined in `androidx.compose.material.Colors::contentColorFor`.